# Como usar a paginação com Laravel DB::select?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel

> testeController.php

```
$jogos = DB::select("select * from jogo where id_u ='$id_u'");
```

Esse é o código que desejo paginar na `View` usando `blade`

> jogo.blade.php

```
{!! $jogos->links() !!}

$jogos = DB::select("select * from jogo where id_u ='$id_u' ")->paginate(2);
```

Já tentei, mas não funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando é utilizado o [DB::select](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries) o seu retorno é um [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array.php) de [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.classes.php) sem paginação, é o modo de fazer [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) da maneira simples e sem grandes recursos, ou seja, não tem os métodos do [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries) que está precisando para gerar uma ***paginação de resultados***. A maneira mais simples para gerar uma paginação no [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel):

```
\DB::table('jogo')->where('id_u',$id_u)->paginate();
```

agora com essa [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries) será gerado a paginação ao qual precisa, ou seja, a única maneira de fazer uma paginação de resultados no [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) conforme a sua [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5) é com [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries).

***Referencias:***

- [DB::select](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries)
- [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array.php)
- [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.classes.php)
- [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)
- [Laravel: Documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5)